# Leading Zero in my digital clock

Tags: javascript

Hi I am building a digital clock and i want it to look nicer by adding a leading zero, but i cant seem to make it work somebody who can give me a tip?

I have tried if(hour <  10) { hour = "0" + hour;}

But that didnt work

```
const DATE = new Date();
var monthNames = ["January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var dayNames = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wendesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
console.log(DATE);

document.getElementById('year').innerHTML = DATE.getFullYear();
document.getElementById('month').innerHTML = monthNames[DATE.getMonth()];
document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = DATE.getDate();
document.getElementById('day').innerHTML = dayNames[DATE.getDay() - 1];

var hour = document.getElementById('hour').innerHTML = DATE.getHours();
var min = document.getElementById('minute').innerHTML = DATE.getMinutes();
var sec = document.getElementById('second').innerHTML = DATE.getSeconds();

var theTime = document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = hour + " : " + min + " : " + sec;
```

My HTML looks like this

```
<div id="myClock">
    <div id="period">
    <span id="year"></span>
        <span id="month"></span>
        <span id="date"></span>
        <span id="day"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="time">
        <span id="hour"></span>
        <span id="minute"></span>
        <span id="second"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<form>
    <input type="date" class="unstyled">
    <input type="time">
</form>
<div id="alarmBox">
    <div class="box">
        <h1>alarm</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML too?

Comment: You can edit the question and add the HTML. Putting it in the comment isnt really helpful.

Comment: @TommyO would you rewrite the entire js code or ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the code below would work as your solution. I padded the `hour` and the `min` variable because you would run into the same issue for both variables.

The `Date` functions you called to set the variables have a return type of `number`. Your code was adding 0 to a number, which basically does nothing. You want to concatenate a string, so just make sure your variable is a `string` first.

```js
const DATE = new Date();
var monthNames = ["January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var dayNames = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wendesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
console.log(DATE);

document.getElementById('year').innerHTML = DATE.getFullYear();
document.getElementById('month').innerHTML = monthNames[DATE.getMonth()];
document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = DATE.getDate();
document.getElementById('day').innerHTML = dayNames[DATE.getDay() - 1];

var hour = document.getElementById('hour').innerHTML = DATE.getHours();
var min = document.getElementById('minute').innerHTML = DATE.getMinutes();
var sec = document.getElementById('second').innerHTML = DATE.getSeconds();

//change the vars types to string and check if it's 1 or 2 digits
hour = hour.toString()
if (hour.length < 2) {
  //prepend a 0 to the string to pad if necessary
  hour = '0' + hour;
}
min = min.toString()
if (min.length < 2) {
  //prepend a 0 to the string to pad if necessary
  min = '0' + min;
}

var theTime = document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = hour + " : " + min + " : " + sec;
```

```html
<div id="myClock">
  <div id="period">
    <span id="year"></span>
    <span id="month"></span>
    <span id="date"></span>
    <span id="day"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="time">
    <span id="hour"></span>
    <span id="minute"></span>
    <span id="second"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<form>
  <input type="date" class="unstyled">
  <input type="time">
</form>
<div id="alarmBox">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>alarm</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```